# Is spilt layout good to display active and non-active products after user sign in to their saas account?

Tags: dashboard, features, administration, multiple-products

[image]

I have created a wireframe for this.

Am I doing it correct or is there any other best way in UX/UI?

My goal is to upsell/promote non-active products.

Why My question here is different?
Its different because, I asked about the layout. eg: is it good idea according to my wireframe to place active and non-active products to increase visibility?

**Please note this will be the first page the user will see after they LOG In.**

Comment: How about displaying the inactive services in **black and white** (with coloured "try 30 days for free" or similar) vs the active in **colour**? And adding a checkbox "Display activated services only"?

Comment: Would this question help you? [Best way to show an “unactivated” part of an app?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/111666/best-way-to-show-an-unactivated-part-of-an-app/111671#111671).

Comment: @Mike I changed my query to better explain.

Comment: Also,  what is your plan if the user has 6 or more active products?

Answer (score 1):

My first opinion is this, the active products should be on the left, if this is a Western application as we read left to right in a Z pattern. I can imagine it being frustrating if the upsell products were the items in the primary zone for a user.